Can Fern-Wifi be installed on Ubuntu 24.4?
Is it possible to install fern WiFi cracker on Ubuntu 24.4 without breaking my system? Iv tried a few tutorials online i have found to no avail.

Yes it is possible. Is that all you need to know? This is the page to use: https://github.com/savio-code/fern-wifi-cracker

yes iv read that i just couldnt get it to work for some reason?

Figured it out i forgot Macchanger lol
